# Multiple DataStores exception in Android Instrumentation Test

Tags: android, android-testing

I have an Android Instrumentation Test class which is supposed to test the DataStore I'm using. But when I add more than one Test to the class I get the following error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: /data/user/0/com.example.app/files/datastore/example_test.preferences_pb. You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$file$2.invoke(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:168)
```

This is the test class

```kotlin
private const val PREFERENCES = "example_test"

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleTest {

    private val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
    private val dataStore = PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
        scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()),
        produceFile = { context.preferencesDataStoreFile(PREFERENCES) }
    )

    @Test
    fun testOne() {
        runBlocking {
            dataStore.edit {
                it[stringPreferencesKey("bla")] = "bla"
            }
        }

    }

    @Test
    fun testTwo() {
        runBlocking {
            dataStore.edit {
                it[stringPreferencesKey("bla")] = "bla"
            }
        }

    }
}
```

As soon as I comment out `testTwo()` it works nicely. I don't understand why a second DataStore is created.

Answer (score 2):

JUnit will create a new instance of the test class and thus all the fields on it for each test, to help ensure there's no shared state between them that could cause unreliable, inconsistent tests.

Since the DataStore is being created every time it does that, but presumably will be lazily cleaned up (typical JVM GC approach), when it creates another you've got multiple active ones in the process. That's not allowed since multiple instances pointing at the same file could cause errors.

If your example above is pared down from your real code, and in the real thing you're testing your own code, something more interesting, more worth testing: wrap the data store so you can substitute it. With a basic preferences interface you could swap out the implementation in tests with a simple map-based implementation. Then you also avoid doing file IO in tests (generally a no-no since it's slow and introduces shared state between tests).

If you really are trying to just test the actual DataStore then the answer would simply be don't write that test: don't test library code, only test your own code.

Or perhaps you're writing an end-to-end / feature test, and want it as close as possible to testing the whole app without lots of test doubles. In that case maybe you really want to use the real data store in your test. If that's the case then you can use the [property delegate the docs advocate since it ensures a singleton, and make sure it's outside the test class, global scope (and not in multiple files)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#preferences-create). Then it will only get called once. Be wary of state persisted between tests in that case though; you may want to clear the data store in a cleanup function (@After) or test rule.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Data Store object inside a simple Repository class. That repository class should be a singleton (via Dagger or something else). That was the main cause of this issue in my case.